# Calling Javascript function in an external file through php file?

Tags: javascript, php

Javascript code (In another file in the same directory):

```
function js(str)
{
 alert(str);
}
```

PHP code(in current file):

```
<?php
echo '<script  type="text/javascript" src="C:\xampp2\htdocs\ARD\call_jsfunc_diff_page.js">  </script>';
echo '<script>js("hello!!")</script>';
?>
```

I have checked on many links on the internet, i think i'm doing the right way, but the javascript function js(str) doesn't get called !!

Can somebody help me please ??

Comment: Before you edit the question, you are calling the wrong function and give the relative src than giving the absolute path.

Comment: First of all, is the path to your external js-file correct? Try adding `alert('Hello')` at top of that file, so you know it is called. 
Second: Do you get an error in your console (something like 'call to undefined function js'?). It's possible the function isn't initialized yet at the moment you call it. Try setting a timeout before calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

Before you edited the question: You called the function `js` but you are trying to call the `func` function.

Access to local hard disks is also problematic. Use a relative URI and access the `.js` over HTTP instead.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?